# why helm-projectile-recentf set current buffer as default

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-helm

I'm trying move from ido-mode to `helm` and `projectile` and are not used to, something will be overcome, but when I tried `helm-projectile-recentf`, I wish it can switch to last buffer I visited quickly, but the default buffer is my current buffer, I don't want to switch to my current buffer, I have to move down first. switch buffer is a very frequent operation, I think move down everytime is very annoying!

I have studied `helm-projectile-recentf` function, it seems it is not easy to customize it to suit my normal requirement.

Could somebody have good suggestion, thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend using helm-mini to do that. It may be configured what to display. Check this [great tutorial!](https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) about helm. Besides that, you can use C-x right/left arrow to cycle your buffers quickly (I guess this function is built-in).

Comment: Thanks, but helm-mini show all buffers but not project-specified buffer, and C-x right/left need my hands away off alphabet area, it is not convenience.

Comment: The problem is that recentf is updated only when you open a file, not when you move through buffers. You maybe can use `projectile-project-buffers-other-buffer` to change buffers.